# Serialize and Deserialize UserControl Dependency Properties in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl. I want to save the Dependency Properties as a serialization in a file and then Deserialize and Read them again. Does anyone help me?

UserControl Source:

```
    <Grid >
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Family}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Code Behinde:

```
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), null);

    public string Family
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FamilyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FamilyProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FamilyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Family", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1),null);
```

I'm not familiar with view models. How can I use view models?

Comment: i would consider using a model class.

Comment: You can't serialise a dependency object. So you're going to need some other class to serialise. That could be a viewmodel or dto. Or some other mechanism such as building xml directly.

Comment: That's just two strings. Write them to a file, or better, to [user settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings). Then read them back, create a new control instance, and set the two properties from the strings you've read.